# F# processing csv, parsing record by record

Tags: csv, f#

I'm new to F# basically i'm attempting to use the FileHelpers library to import the csv record by record. So i can then place each object in a queue.

```
let importOrders (filePath:string) = do
       let engine = new FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<DataTypes.Order.OrderType>)
       engine.BeginReadFile(filePath)
       for o in engine do
         unProccessedData.Enqueue(o)
```

However its saying that engine is not a type who's value can be enumerated yet it implements IEnumerable. Anyone got any suggestions on a possible fix or a different approach.

I need to be able to process the csv record by record, converting each into the orderType and then storing the order onto the queue. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `engine` (which is called `FileHelperAsyncEngine`) only implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`, but it does not implement generic `IEnumerable<T>` which is required by the F# compiler.

You'll need to cast the non-generic `IEnumerable` to generic `IEnumerable<obj>` (or to some other instantiation of the generic type, depending on what is the type of values in the collection). The following should do the trick:

```
let importOrders (filePath:string) = 
    let engine = new FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<OrderType>) 
    engine.BeginReadFile(filePath) 
    for o in engine |> Seq.cast<obj> do // NOTE: Conversion using Seq.cast
        unProccessedData.Enqueue(o)
```